# CSS Media Query Not Working for Devices Widths 1000px and Greater

Tags: html, css

For some reason my CSS media query is not working for device widths 1001px and up. I have never seen this occur before with any of my prior projects. Any suggestions?

My media queries for devices that are 1000px and below is working fine. I have updated Chrome, cleared my cache, and still nothing. Here is my CSS...

```
style {

@media only screen and (min-width: 1001px) and (max-width: 1500px) {

  /* --- NAV ---*/

  .navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2rem 1.5rem;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 33px -18px gray;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav-item {
    margin-left: 2rem;
  }
  .nav-link {
    font-size: 13pt;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #8f8f8f;
  }

  /* --- BODY ---*/

  .header-div {
    filter: brightness(100%);
    height: 23rem;
  }
  #header-image {
    max-width: 100%;
    filter: brightness(80%);
    margin-top: 2rem;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  .header-h1 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-weight: 400;
    width: 20rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    margin-top: -16rem;
  }
  .header-h2 {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    font-size: 15pt;
    padding-left: 2rem;
  }
  .first-button {
    color: black;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 4px 11px;
    border: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all linear 0.4s;
    margin-left: 2rem;
  }
  .first-button:hover {
    color: white;
    background: black;
  }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Delete `style {` on the first line.

Stylesheets don't need a style element selector.

Comment: The only reason I had put the style element selector in there was for the purpose of adding the code to the question. My actual code does not have it, as the stylesheet is in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1001px) and (max-width: 1500px) {

  /* --- NAV ---*/

  .navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2rem 1.5rem;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 33px -18px gray;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav-item {
    margin-left: 2rem;
  }
  .nav-link {
    font-size: 13pt;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #8f8f8f;
  }

  /* --- BODY ---*/

  .header-div {
    filter: brightness(100%);
    height: 23rem;
  }
  #header-image {
    max-width: 100%;
    filter: brightness(80%);
    margin-top: 2rem;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  .header-h1 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-weight: 400;
    width: 20rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    margin-top: -16rem;
  }
  .header-h2 {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    font-size: 15pt;
    padding-left: 2rem;
  }
  .first-button {
    color: black;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 4px 11px;
    border: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all linear 0.4s;
    margin-left: 2rem;
  }
  .first-button:hover {
    color: white;
    background: black;
  }
}
```

I deleted the style {

}

You used "style" as a [selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and put the media query in it